# Get build files to persist on host after docker-compose build is run

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to run a `docker-compose build` command with a Dockerfile and a docker-compose.yml file.

Inside the docker-compose.yml file, I'm trying to bind a local folder on the host machine `./dist` with a folder on the container `app/dist`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  dev:
    build:
      context: .
    volumes:
      - ./dist:app/dist # I'm expecting files to be changed or added to the container's app/dist to be reflected to the host's ./dist folder
```

Inside the Dockerfile, I build some files with an NPM script that I'm wanting to make available on the host machine once the build is finished. I'm also touching a new file inside the `/app/dist/test.md` just as a simple test to see if the file ends up on the host machine, but it does not.

```sh
FROM node:8.17.0-alpine as example

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

RUN npm install
RUN npm run dist
RUN touch /app/dist/test.md
```

Is there a way to do this? I also tried using the "long syntax" as mentioned in the Docker Compose v3 documentation: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to install Node and run the `npm` commands directly on the host.

```sh
$BREW_OR_APT_GET_OR_YUM_OR_SOMETHING install node
npm install
npm run dist
# done
```

There's not an easy way to use a Dockerfile to build host content.  The Dockerfile can't write out directly to the host filesystem; if you use a volume mount, the host volume hides the container content before anything else happens.

That means, if you want to use this approach, you need to launch a temporary container to get the content out.  You can do it with a one-off container, mounting the host directory somewhere other than `/app`, making the main container command be `cp`:

```sh
sudo docker build -t myimage .
sudo docker run --rm \
  -v "$PWD/dist:/out" \
  myimage \
  cp -a /app/dist /out
```

Or, if you specifically wanted to use `docker cp`:

```sh
sudo docker build -t myimage .
sudo docker create --name to-copy myimage
sudo docker cp -r to-copy:/app/dist ./dist
sudo docker rm to-copy
```

Note that any of these sequences are more complex than just installing a local Node via a package manager, and require administrator permissions (you can use the same technique to overwrite any host file, including the `/etc/shadow` file with encrypted passwords).